# can't install npm package in google cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am new in using google cloud functions. I am trying to use expressjs in the my google cloud functions folder. I run `npm i express` on my terminal. but I get errors like this

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/muchammadagunglaksana/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/muchammadagunglaksana/package.json'
npm WARN muchammadagunglaksana No description
npm WARN muchammadagunglaksana No repository field.
npm WARN muchammadagunglaksana No README data
npm WARN muchammadagunglaksana No license field.

+ express@4.17.1
updated 1 package and audited 17547 packages in 4.294s
```

it seems the package is installed, but the express dependecies is not automatically added on package.json

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change directory (`cd`) to your functions folder before running the command.  npm assumes that package.json is in the current working directory in order to make changes to it.